# how to make an element fixed when the window resizes

Tags: html, css

I have a registration form where the there is icons in the form input. When i resize the window it displaces (squeezes) which is very annoying can anyone tell me what should i do to make it fixes in the place where it is.

```css
#username-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15%;
}

#password-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15%;
}

#email-logo {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 40px;
  left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form-container">
  <h1 id="linklist">Register</h1>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
  <i class="fas fa-user" id="username-logo"></i>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
  <i class="fas fa-lock" id="password-logo"></i>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
  <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="email-logo"></i>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Comment: Are you asking about the icons or input field being fixed

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the icon and input and from there you can style it easier. The placement of the icon all depends on the design you have.

```css
.register-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 20rem;
}

.input-container {
  display: flex;
}

.input-container input {}

.input-container i {}
```

```html
<h1 id="linklist">Register</h1>

<form id="form-container" class="register-form">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required">
    <i class="fas fa-user" id="username-logo"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required="required">
    <i class="fas fa-lock" id="password-logo"></i>
  </div>

  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="required">
    <i class="fas fa-envelope" id="email-logo"></i>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="button">Register</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your container `position: relative` and logo `position: absolute` and reposition using `left/right/top/bottom` .
This way the logo's will be positioned according to container (here `input`) not according to body and will not displaces on resize if used correctly